# retrieve a header from a file in c

Tags: c, file, bit-fields

I have a file from which I would like to retrieve the header, the header is in network order (big endian) and I would like to store it in this structure:

```
struct record {
    
    unsigned int type : 15;
    unsigned int f : 1; 
    unsigned int length : 16;

    char* payload;
    unsigned int uuid: 32;


};
```

I would just like to store the header which is 32 bits long. It has three parts that go in the following order: type, footer, and length. They each respectively have a length of 15,1 and 16 bits. I was wondering how I should go about storing these values in the bitfields of my structure.

I also need to find the number of octets/bytes contained in the message (with the header included)

Note:
the file contains a continuous message in binary with no breaks (from what I've understood).

edit:
this is the format of the message:

```
0            15 16             31
+-------------+-+--------------+
|TYPE         |F|    LENGTH    |
+------------------------------+
|                              |
             PAYLOAD
+                              +

|                              |
+------------------------------+
|            (UUID)            |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please post a sample file and possibly a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Bit fields are explicitely under specified. Specifically, you cannot be sure of the order of the fields. All that is guaranteed is that a system is consistent with itself, but if you want to exchange messages, you'd better avoid them...

Comment: @SergeBallesta if I could, I would just avoid c to begin with.

Comment: Well, do you know where to start? Ex. did you open the file? Read 4 first bytes? What _specific_ problem are you having problem with? Read 4 bytes from file, convert them into the values to be stored in bitfields, get the file size minus 4 bytes, read the rest of file into dynamically allocated payload, read last 4 bytes store them in uuid.

Comment: My first problem would be reading the first four bytes then being able to retrieve the type, footer, and length. for now, i have this : ```uint32_t header;
    fread(&header , sizeof(uint32_t), 1 , f);
    ntohl(header);```   ps: i don't know how to change lines

Comment: Unfortunately, most implementations of other languages are written in C, and the bit-field problem is just something that was initially under specified, that different compilers implemented differently and that in the end real world programmers decided not to use when it comes to exchanging data. It is fine as soon as it is only for local use or for in memory operation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I will use this information to rally the students and denounce the professor in order the save the future generations of this suffering

Comment: `fread(&header , sizeof(uint32_t), 1 , f);` No, don't read it into single value, act on bytes. You read 4 bytes. Then convert 4 bytes to values you want to have. Something along: `unsigned char bytes[4]; fread(bytes, ...); type = 0xAFFFF & (bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]); f = bytes[1] >> 7; length = bytes[3] << 8 | bytes[2]`

Comment: Is the payload padded (upto 4 octet - boundaries) ?

Comment: @KamilCuk in my case for the fread funciton i should have something like this ? ```fread(bytes, sizeof(char), 4, f); ```

Comment: @wildplasser no it can be unlimited but its length in bytes is written in the "length" part of the header.

Comment: In that case the UUID can be unaligned. And the total message size can be not a multiple of 4 octets, too.

Comment: @wildplasser the header is 4 bytes long but not the entire message in bytes the message should be r->length + 4 (or +8 depending on if the uuid is included) bytes long

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> the header is in network order (big endian)
>
> ```
>  |TYPE         |F|    LENGTH    |
> ```
>
> how I should go about storing these values in the bitfields of my structure.

As I interpret it:

```
    v- most significant bit of first byte
           v- least significant bit of first byte
   |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|F|               |
                  ^- Least significant bit of "type"
    ^- Most significant bit of "type"
   field "type" has 15 bits
```

Read the bytes from the file, then convert bytes to the values. I think that would be something along the following, but I am not sure of that `bytes[1] >> 1` stuff:

```
struct record output;

unsigned char bytes[4];
fread(bytes, sizeof(bytes), 1, file); // read first 4 bytes

// Convert 4 bytes to values you want to have.
output.type = bytes[0] << 7 | bytes[1] >> 1;
output.f = bytes[1] & 0x1;
output.length = bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3];
```

Comment: I, unfortunately, i have the value in big-endian but in the structure i have to convert to little-endian how would do the conversion?

Comment: `output.type = (bytes[0] << 7) | (bytes[1] >> 1);`

Comment: @a_confused_student `in the structure i have to convert to little-endian` I do not follow. It's not relevant how structure holds - it holds a "value"  - a number.